# Calculating BMI through Python: Take 2

Tags: python

Sorry about my previous question. The question I have to answer is this:

Body Mass Index (BMI) is a good indicator of body fatness for most people. The formula for BMI is weight/ height2 where weight is in kilograms and height is in meters. Write a program that prompts for weight in pounds and height in inches, converts the values to metric, and then calculates and displays the BMI value.

What I have so far is this:

```
"""
BMI Calculator

1. Obtain weight in pounds and height in inches
2. Convert weight to kilograms and height to meters
3. Calculate BMI with the formula weight/height^2
"""

#prompt user for input from keyboard
weight= input ("How much do you weigh (in pounds)?")
#this get's the person's weight in pounds

weight_in_kg= weight/2.2
#this converts weight to kilograms

height= input ("What is your height (in inches)?")
#this gets the person's height in inches

height_in_meter=height*2.54
#this converts height to meters

bmi=weight_in_kg/(height_in_meters*2)
#this calculates BMI

print (BMI)
```

My first step works, but that is the easy part. I know  that in Python the equal sign assigns something, so I'm not sure if that is the problem, but I really do not know what to do. I am really sorry. When I run the program it says:

TypeError : unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'

If anyone could give me any tips on what I am doing wrong, I would really appreciate it. And if not, thank you for your time. Thanks again.

Comment: Your problem is you're trying to multiply a string `str` by a `float`. if you wrap the offending string in `float(string)` that should solve the problem. Edit - beaten to the answer by @ezod.

Comment: Yes. Python 3.2 for Windows.

Comment: In Python3, `input` returns a `str`. You could use `weight = float(input("How much do you weigh (in pounds)?"))` to make sure weight is converted to a float, etc.

Comment: By the way I think you meant `height_in_meters ** 2` - that is, height _squared_ rather than height times 2.

Comment: It's worth noting that Python is case sensitive (e.g. BMI and bmi are not the same) so the variable in the print statement should be bmi.

Comment: Also comments typically go before or next to a statement. This'll become more obvious as you write bigger programs but it's good practice to start off that way.

Comment: I corrected the input and the formula for bmi using the **2 to square it. I got an answewr... but according to this website, http://nhlbisupport.com/bmi/ , I am not getting the right answer.

Comment: I really appreciate all of your help!

Comment: @LizS Nice job rewriting the question.  Check the units on your height conversion.  According to your formula, I'm ~170 meters tall - or about 1.5 football fields ;)

Comment: Thank you @ernie. So then would I use height_in_meters=height*.0254?

Comment: @LizS try it and see!  You could throw in a `print(height_in_meter)` (or meters? you've got both in your example?) to try and see if the numbers you're getting make sense.

Comment: I really appreciate all of you help!! :)

Comment: @LizS you're welcome, and welcome to SO!  make sure to mark ezod's answer as right (there's a checkmark to the left) and upvote as well if it helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Python 3.x (as specified):**

The problem is that keyboard input from `input()` is of type `str` (string), which is not a numeric type (even if the user types in numbers). However, this is easily fixed by changing the input lines like so:

```
weight = float(input("How much do you weigh (in pounds)?"))
```

and

```
height = float(input("What is your height (in inches)?"))
```

thus converting the string output of `input()` into the numeric `float` type.

Comment: its worth noting in 2.x this is not true ... and input should be avoided where possible ...

Answer (score 2):

First off, there was a typo: `height_in_meter(S)`.
For Python 2, a preceding `float(...` is not necessary, although I am sure it is good practice.

```
"""
BMI Calculator

1. Obtain weight in pounds and height in inches
2. Convert weight to kilograms and height to meters
3. Calculate BMI with the formula weight/height^2
"""

#prompt user for input from keyboard
weight= input ("How much do you weigh (in pounds)?")
#this get's the person's weight in pounds

weight_in_kg= weight/2.2
#this converts weight to kilograms

height= input ("What is your height (in inches)?")
#this gets the person's height in inches

height_in_meter=height*2.54/100
#this converts height to centimeters

bmi=weight_in_kg/(height_in_meter**2)
#this calculates BMI

print (bmi)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
weight= float(input("How much do you weigh (in kg)?"))
weight_in_kg= float(input("Enter weight in kg?"))


#height= float(input("What is your height (in meters)?"))
height_in_meter= float(input("Enter height in metres?"))


bmi=weight_in_kg/(height_in_meter**2)


print (bmi)
```

I found this was the easiest way to make it work, Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
# height and weight are available as a regular lists

# Import numpy
import numpy as np

# Create array from height with correct units: np_height_m
np_height_m = np.array(height) * 0.0254

# Create array from weight with correct units: np_weight_kg 
np_weight_kg = np.array(weight) * 0.453592

# Calculate the BMI: bmi
bmi =  np_weight_kg / (np_height_m **2)

# Print out bmi
print(bmi)
```